# How to save clipboard or (car kill-ring) as string

Tags: yank, clipboard

OS Debian GNU/Linux 7
emacs-24.3

I want to save the content of the clipboard or the last item of the kill-ring (depending whats newer) as a string so that I can do stuff with it in a eLisp function. At the moment I use this:

```
  (setq zwischenablage (car kill-ring))
```

I have 2 problems at the moment:

1. When the text was copied in emacs and was highlighted something like "#("Wechseln" 0 8 (fontified t face font-lock-doc-face))" is saved in the string. For some reason yank-handled-properties seems not to be applied.
2. When I copy text from outside emacs like the browser or so it is not used. I have to yank it and after this my function works fine.

Does anyone know any solution for these problems?

Comment: `(setq zwischenablage (current-kill 0 t))`. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Kill-Ring.html

Comment: Thx. That did it.

Comment: @muffinmad: Please post your comment as an answer. You might want to also explain why what OP tried doesn't work. OP: please consider accepting muffinmad's answer, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation of the `kill-ring` variable, interact with the kill ring directly is not recommended:

> Since the kill ring is supposed to interact nicely with cut-and-paste
>   facilities offered by window systems, use of this variable should
>   interact nicely with `interprogram-cut-function` and
>   `interprogram-paste-function`.  The functions `kill-new`,
>   `kill-append`, and `current-kill` are supposed to implement this
>   interaction; you may want to use them instead of manipulating the kill
>   ring directly.

In this case solution is `(setq zwischenablage (current-kill 0 t))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 10, and I'm not sure if this answer applies to other OSs; but it may help. I'm currently using Emacs 27.1, and I'm working on my `init.el`. I had a line at the bottom of the file which was preventing the startup screen showing. I wanted a way to move the line to somewhere at the top of my configuration file.

While there are some neat functions to do this (in another Stack Exchange answer), I wanted an out of the box solution. The command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> kills a line from the cursor and it seems to also copy the contents of that line to the clipboard.

What I ended up doing was pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. And to paste, I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.